# Add Google Maps API to Angular project as a component

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to add Google Map as a component to my Angular project. I added the API to `index.html` as follows:

```
<body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY"></script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And a map container and a button to show the map in my `app.component.html` as follows:

```
<button type="button" (click)="open()">Call Map</button>
<div id="map" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw"></div>
```

And the `open` function to `app.component.ts` as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
  open() {
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Everything is fine. I can open the map when I click the button. I guess because of the Asynchronous nature of the Google map API, every time after compiling the code in vscode, I get the following error:

[image]

Do you have any solution for this?

Note: I have added @type/googlemaps to the project and Angular Google Maps (AGM) and other similar libraries are not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add googlemaps type in tsconfig.app.json

**tsconfig.app.json**:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, As I mentioned in the last line of the question, I have already added the type.

Comment: @M.Reza did you add in tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: Yes, I added the "types": ["google"] but still get the error

Comment: @M.Reza add package.json and tsconfig.app.json to the description

Comment: I have added to the question ↑

Comment: It worked with "types": ["googlemaps"]. I did not move the @types/googlemaps to devDependencies. Thanks a lot. Can you explain what was wrong?

Comment: because it is a development package

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file